# Run test in phpunit with specific php version

Tags: php, macos, phpunit, version

I have installed multiple PHP versions on my Mac and want to run unit-tests against a specific PHP version (or against multipls versions)

Here's the php versions I have:

```
$ php --version
  Output: PHP 5.4.23 ...

$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin/php --version
  Output: PHP 5.2.17 ...
```

My test case looks like this:

```
function test_php_version() {
    $actual = phpversion();
    $expected = '5.2.17';
    $this->assertEquals( $expected, $actual, 'Wrong PHP version!' );
}
```

When I run the test I get this response:

```
$ phpunit

  Wrong PHP version!
  Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
  --- Expected
  +++ Actual
  @@ @@
  -'5.2.17'
  +'5.4.24'

$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin/php phpunit
  Error: Could not open input file: phpunit
```

How can I run the tests with the php version 5.2.17?

---

**Update**:

I discover that PHPUnit does not run with php5.2.17 anymore. So I change my requirements to run unit tests with php5.3.5, which is supported.

Comment: How has installed phpunit?

Comment: I installed phpunit by downloading the PHAR archive, as described here: http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin/php path/to/phpunit.phar
```

#### Create a script e.g. `phpunit-using-5.2`

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin/php path/to/phpunit.phar "$@"
```

Now you can run it:

```
$ phpunit-using-5.2
```

Or you can create a bash alias too.

Comment: This works, but actually the phpunit does not run with PHP 5.2 anymore... So I had to slightly change the command from `php5.2.17` to `php5.3.5`

Comment: @Philipp That's right, I forgot, [PHPUnit >= 3.7 requires PHP 5.3.3](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html). [PHPUnit 3.6 supports 5.2.7](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/installation.html) but that version is no longer support and there is no phar for it. But if you need it, it will work.

Comment: And... you just saved my day. Thank you very much!

Comment: 2017, Ubuntu 16.04, PHP5.6, and your solution still helps! I just adapted a bit:

`#!/bin/sh
set -e

/usr/bin/php5.6 /usr/local/bin/phpunit "$@"`

Answer (score 11):

I had two version of php, default is 7.4 and older is 7.3, so I can test my testcase with older version like this.

```
php7.3 ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Comment: I ran a variation of this solution to get it to work on Plesk with Laravel: `/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`

Comment: Thanks.  This was what I needed. phpunit was running with whatever "php" was in the PATH.  This way I can specify that it should run using a specific version of php.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel vagrant box Homestaead has a set of functons

like

```
$ php74
or 
$ php56
```

that set your PHP CLI to a specific version

Alternatively you can set it yourself like that

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.4
```