# how to run phpUnit with a PHP version selected?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, wamp

I am trying execute phpUnit on Windows 10 to test up a Laravel project but the Git Bash window shows me this:

> ```
> Fabian@Fahico_PC MINGW64 ~/code/curso-styde (master)
> $ vendor/bin/phpunit
> output: This version of PHPUnit is supported on PHP 7.1 and PHP 7.2.
> You are using PHP 5.6.31 (C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.31\php.exe).
> ```

while I have PHP versions **5.6.31**, **7.0.23** and **7.1.9** added when intalling WAMP Server, more specifically in `C:\wamp64\bin\php` path.

How I can select a specific PHP version to run phpUnit ?

I tried to [edit the PATH environment](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6113) variable but it didn't work. I don't want [to run another version to phpUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683964/run-test-in-phpunit-with-specific-php-version/24923180) since I have a valid PHP version, I just want know how to change it to execute.

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: If you don't mind may I see your composer.json from your laravel root folder?

Answer (score 0):

on your lower rightmost part of the window look for the wampp icon click on it point to php > Version then select the version you want to use.